# Passing data to the controller JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans-8

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8IF6.png)I'm trying to pass the data (variables) from one stage to another stage, but when I try to access them in the second stage they are null. Code of the mainWindow. Go to window1

```
 public class PrincipalController {
 private Stage primaryStage;
 public void initStage( Stage stage){ primaryStage = stage;}



@FXML
 private void goWindow1(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
         FXMLLoader miCargador = new
                 FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista/Window1.fxml"));
         Parent root = (Parent) miCargador.load();

                     // Access to window driver 1


 Window1Controller window1 = miCargador.
                  <window1Controlador>getController();
      windnow1.initStage(primaryStage);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
     } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

// window1 class:

```
 public class Window1Controlador {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Scene escenaAnterior;
    private String tituloAnterior;
    public void initStage(Stage stage){
         primaryStage = stage;
         escenaAnterior = stage.getScene();
         tituloAnterior = stage.getTitle();
         primaryStage.setTitle("Window 1");
     }
```

If I want to access previous title that I received comes null

```
/**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       System.out.println(""+ this.tituloAnterior);}
```

The initialize shows me null when it should show me "Window1"
}

Comment: Please translate in English and share the exception trace

Comment: I already modified it, you could help me please?

Comment: step 1. Print the object, before loading the Window1 class
2. print the object in the Window1 class.

am sure you are going to be different.

you should now try to pass the object and verify. If it works, that means some where in the configuration you need to bind the class, which is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `initialize()` method is called as part of the process of loading the FXML file - in other words it is called when you call `miCargador.load()`.

Obviously this happens *before* you call `window1.initStage(...)`, so when `initialize()` is invoked, `tituloAnterior` is still null.

The simple solution is just not to access `tituloAnterior` in the `initialize()` method, but to do whatever you need to do with it in the `initStage()` method. E.g.

```
public void initStage(Stage stage){
     primaryStage = stage;
     escenaAnterior = stage.getScene();
     tituloAnterior = stage.getTitle();
     primaryStage.setTitle("Window 1");
     someLabelFromFXML.setText(tituloAnterior);
 }
```

---

If you prefer, you could set the controller for the FXML loader in the Java code:

```
@FXML
private void goWindow1(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
         FXMLLoader miCargador = new
                 FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/vista/Window1.fxml"));

         Window1Controller window1 = new Window1Controller();
         window1.initStage(primaryStage);
         miCargador.setController(window1);

         Parent root = (Parent) miCargador.load();

                     // Access to window driver 1



      Scene scene = new Scene(root);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
     } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Then remove the `fx:controller` attribute from your FXML file. This way the `initStage()` method is called before the `load()` method, and `tituloAnterior` will not be null when `initialize()` is called.

Comment: How I remove the fx:controller attribute from my FXML file?

Comment: @MelDiaz Just delete it?

Comment: from window1.fxml?

Comment: @MelDiaz Yes, from `window1.fxml`. You only need that if you are using the second solution (setting the controller in Java code). As I said in the answer, I think it's simpler just to avoid accessing the properties you set in the `initialize()` method in the first place.

Comment: but, Which of the fx:controller I have to remove?

Comment: why did you call to miCargador.setController(window1)?, when i do that the progam don´t executed Parent root = (Parent) miCargador.load(). The next page don't apear. When I quit this line -->miCargador.setController(window1), the second windows apear but the initialize don´t have the correct values.

Comment: @MelDiaz Which of my two solutions are you trying to implement?

Comment: The second solution.

Comment: @MelDiaz I don't understand "Which of the fx:controller I have to remove?". An FXML file has only one `fx:controller` attribute. If you are calling `setController(...)`, on the FXML loader, you must not have a `fx:controller` attribute in the corresponding FXML file, so you need to delete the `fx:controller` attribute from `Window1.fxml` if you are using the second solution.

Comment: but when I do make Controller it apear again. If i quit  the controller how i control the windows1?

Comment: @MelDiaz I don't understand that last comment (what does it mean to "quit the controller"?). Look, each UI loaded from an FXML has a controller associated with it. There are two ways to create the controller. You can do it "by hand" by creating the controller object and calling `setController` on the FXML loader, before you load the FXML. Or you can ask the `FXMLLoader` to create the controller for you, by using a `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file, specifying the class to use to create the controller instance. You must not do both of those, but either one will give you a controller.

Comment: I have added an image of how my class is right now at the top of this question. In my question I put a very simple example of the same situation, but that is my project. I delete the controler by entering the window1.fxml and delete the controller, but if a in that same fxml pulse in make controler, the controller that I had removed before appears again.

Comment: @MelDiaz I don't understand the last part of that comment: "if a in that same fxml pulse in make controler, the controller that I had removed before appears again". You're saying that you delete the `fx:controller` attribute, and it mysteriously re-appears? What does "if a in that same fxml pulse in make controler" mean?

Comment: In the window1.fxml, if I press the right mouse button, the options appear make controller, and this again generates the driver that I had manually deleted.

Comment: @MelDiaz I don't understand what you mean. Press the right mouse button in what? Your editor? What editor are you using? Why do you choose the option to add the `fx:controller` attribute back in if you don't want it any more?

Comment: Yes, it is in the editor, because if I modify something and do not do the driver does not update the modifications.

Comment: @MelDiaz What editor is this? What do you mean by "driver"? I don't understand "if I modify something and do not do the driver does not update the modifications". What does that mean?

Comment: I'm using net beans and scene builder, driver is controller. if I modify something in fxml with the scene builder, i have to update the fxml with the button make controller

Comment: @MelDiaz Oh, you're using scene builder... Which version? My version certainly doesn't force me to use a controller class in the way you are describing. Did you remove the Controller Class from the field in the "Controller" panel in the bottom left?

Comment: but I need the controller class =(

Comment: net bean IDE 8.2

Comment: @MelDiaz What do you mean, you need the controller class? You still have the controller class, you are just not asking the FXML loader to instantiate it any more. Remove the reference to it from Scene Builder: that creates the `fx:controller` attribute that you do not want.

Comment: @MelDiaz What version of *Scene Builder*?

Comment: Scene Builder 8.2. So, the button make controller only creates a instance of mi controller class?

Comment: @MelDiaz The `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file, as I explained about an hour ago, instructs the FXML Loader to instantiate the controller class for you. If you are instantiating it yourself and calling `setController()` on the FXML Loader, then you obviously do not want the FXML loader to instantiate it. Scene Builder is just a tool for generating the FXML. The "Controller Class" text field in the "Controller" pane generates the `fx:controller` attribute for you. I have no idea what "button" you are talking about.

Comment: Have I to remove from this line ? -----> <VBox maxHeight = "- Infinity" anchoMax = "- Infinity" minHeight = "- Infinity" minWidth = "- Infinity" prefHeight = "400.0" prefWidth = "600,0" de espaciamiento = "5.0" xmlns = "http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns: fx = "http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx: Controlador = "cinema.FXMLVenta2Controller"> ------ - ----- The part of "fx: Controlador = "cinema.FXMLVenta2Controller" ???

Comment: Why would you remove that? All I am telling you to do is to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from `Window1.fxml`. You can do that in Scene Builder simply by deleting "packagename. Window1Controlador" from the text field labelled "Controller Class" in the "Controller" pane. This is not rocket science. If this is too difficult for you, why don't you just use my first solution instead of my second solution?

Comment: When I do it that you has said me, the program stop in the line         
          Parent root = (Parent) miCargador.load();. This line never end